# Alternative to APNS or WNS for linux environment

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, apple-push-notifications

In Apple we have APNS service, which works by having your server PUSH data to Apple's server and your iPhone pulls data from Apple's server. Apple manages how the data gets from Apple's servers to the device and an API manages how the data gets to your app.
Similarly, Windows has the WNS.

Is there some similar service available for the linux environment(for Ubuntu) where the application can receive notifications even when my application is not running?